Dereference symlinks in CMake source distribution tarballs
Some Background
I'm using CMake V3.29.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 to build a project. The product is only for use on a server within my company. In order to deploy the product I would like to generate a .tar.gz distributable tarball by using CPack that ships with CMake.
The Problem
I have common code that I use in other of my projects that I share by setting up symlinks to shared code directories. This works fairly well for my purpose, but now that I want to build a distributable I'm ending up with symlinks in the resulting tarball instead of the actual .cpp and .hpp source code files.
My C++ project is structured as follows. Note the symlink'd directories!
src/
   CMakeLists.txt
   main.cpp
   foo.hpp
   foo.cpp
   database/
      CMakeLists.txt
      create_db.hpp
      create_db.cpp
   infrastructure/
      CMakeLists.txt
      return_codes.hpp
      runtime_configuration.hpp
      runtime_configuration.cpp
   toolbox/
      CMakeLists.txt
      exceptions/           <-----   <-- Symlink to a shared directory
         CMakeLists.txt
         ext_std_exception.hpp
         program_terminate_error.hpp
         program_terminate_error.cpp
      work-queue/           <-----   <-- Symlink to a shared directory
         CMakeLists.txt
         work_queue.hpp
         basic_work_queue_processor.hpp
         basic_work_queue_entry.hpp

When I use cpack --config CPackSourceConfig.cmake, the exceptions/ and work-queue/ directories are created as symlinks in the .tar.gz file.
Some Visuals
The CMakeFiles.txt file in the src/toolbox/exceptions directory looks like this:
add_library(exceptions_ext_filesystem_error OBJECT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ext_filesystem_error.hpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ext_filesystem_error.cpp)
add_library(exceptions_os_error OBJECT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/os_error.hpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/os_error.cpp)
add_library(exceptions_program_terminate_error OBJECT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/program_terminate_error.hpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/program_terminate_error.cpp)

add_library(ql_toolbox_exceptions
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:exceptions_ext_filesystem_error>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:exceptions_os_error>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:exceptions_program_terminate_error>
)


The CMakeLists.txt files in the parent directories have cascading include statements, e.g.:
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/exceptions/CMakeLists.txt)

Help Me Please
I need to know if there is a way to configure CMake to dereference directory symlinks and include the source code files in them instead of creating symlinks.
There is plenty of help available on the interwebs for creating symlinks in a CMake project, but nothing if one wants to go the opposite way and dereference symlinks for the build.
I Tried
I tried this, without success:
install(
    TARGETS my-project
    DESTINATION bin
    ARCHIVE
          COMPONENT Development
          NAMELINK_SKIP
)

CMAKE_INSTALL_MODE has a COPY option, but that's already the default and setting it (unsurprisingly) has no effect.
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_RESOLVE_SYMLINKS does not seem useful for this purpose either.
There are also no usable options for the include() statement to force symlink dereferencing.
My Options

First prize would be to find that magical DEREFERENCE_DIR_SYMLINK option for the `include(...) command. But I doubt if it exists.
Package the shared code into a separate shared library. Even though this probably the professional way to go, it's not ideal; I would just like to package all the code into a single distributable tarball without bothering with libraries.
Copy all the source code to another directory before building and have to copy sort out the symlinks. Not altogether an awful solution but it adds an non-obvious step to the process.
Exclude the symlink directories from the tarball and set them up again on the target machine. This is ugly.

I would appreciate it if someone with CMake experience can help me. I'm at the level where I read the Mastering CMake book and started building this project.
